# set SRC of image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this script:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  $('.stam').on('click', function() {
    $('.new-image').val($(this).attr("data"));
  });
});
```

This script take attribute "Data" and set on "new-image" value. But i wont insert attribute `data` inside `src=" "` of `new-image`. is possibile?

HTML:

```
<img class="new-image" src="--data value here--">
```

Comment: can you please show your HTML as well

Comment: To set the value of `src` attribute, use `.attr('src', 'value')`

Comment: use `.attr` as suggested here by @Tushar and an answer is already here.

Comment: Btw reading your code, just looks like you would have better to delegate click event...

Answer (score 2):

Use `attr()` instead of `val()` like this.

```
$('.new-image').attr('src', $(this).attr("data"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use .prop() instead of val().

   `$('.new-image').prop('src', $(this).attr("data"));`
2. Store src in "data-src" attribute( like data-src="myUrl")- then you could write this way:

   `$('.new-image').prop('src', $(this).data("src"));`